# Determine existence of cycle in number stream - pattern recognition for a cycle

Tags: r, random, cycle, prng

I have tried to make a pseudo Random Number Generator and generated 10000 numbers. I want to determine whether there exists a cycle in it? With my logic, there could be a cycle of maximum length `(INT_MAX)**15` - generating and testing till that value is kind of not feasible. So, is there a way to recognize with N generated numbers(sufficiently large - 10007 numbers) to estimate what length of cycle will be there?

Possibly in R?

Comment: By "cycle" do you mean sequence?

Comment: In addition to hlovdal's answer, there's the question of uniformity.  Some early PRNGs had long cycles but predictable asymmetric densities (kind of like the Universe :-) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is probably much more complex that you would like it to be. Testing weaknesses in PRNGs is not a simple question, and it is highly dependent on the algorithm used for the PRNG. If your PRNG is of type [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), then a test called  [spectral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_test) can be used. For other types of PRNGs there are other tests.

The paper 
[TestU01: A C Library for Empirical Testing of Random Number Generators](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/testu01.pdf) discusses theory and contains software examples on how to test various types.